# When deduping JSON records in a Dask bag, is there a better option than .distinct() - one that reduces memory usage?

Tags: python, dask

I have been trying to work on a few GB of text files containing JSON records on each line. When working with some of the files, I found some duplicated records. There *are* unique IDs (key name UID) on each records, so identifying dupes should be easy.

I have tried importing all the JSON into a Dask bag, filtering down to the keys I am interested in, and then running .distinct(). The chain looks like this:

```
def get_keys(record):
  return (r['UID'],r['DATETIME'],r['USER'],r['PAGEID'],r['ACTION'])

items = (db.read_text('/*.json')
          .map(json.loads)
          .map(get_keys)
          .distinct()
          .to_dataframe(columns=['UID','TIMESTAMP','USER_ID','PID','A'])
          .compute())

items.to_csv('deduped_items.csv')
```

I run this on my laptop, so a Local Client. What ends up happening is the workers restart when hitting 95% memory usage. It seems to retry a few times before throwing an exception. While watching the Dask dashboard, I see that all the partitions from bag-from-delayed are handled, most of distinct-part are handled, then it can't get through distinct-agg.

Should the code block above work, or will I always hit memory limitations

-- edit

I am rerunning this after learning about the key parameter in distinct. Will update with results if it helps.

`.distinct(key=lambda x:x[0])`

-- edit 2

The distinct with key also ran out of memory. I am now going to rearrange to this:

```
   .map(get_keys)
   .to_dataframe(columns=['UID','TIMESTAMP','USER_ID','PID','A'])
   .drop_duplicates()
   .compute())
```

This is running now, and the task graph looks the same, but it appears to be running faster.

-- edit 3

That did not help either. I am starting to believe that the number of duplicates relative to the number of total records is making this difficult. Rough estimate, there are about 50 million records and guessing under 10k duplicates.

-- edit 4

I am now trying to set the UID as the index and doing map_partitions. My understanding is that duplicated UIDs will be guaranteed to exist in the same partition?

```
items = (db.read_text('/*.json')
          .map(json.loads)
          .map(get_keys)
          .to_dataframe(columns=['UID','TIMESTAMP','USER_ID','PID','A'])
          .set_index('UID')
          .map_partitions(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates)
          .compute())
```

Comment: How many keys are there?

Comment: Updated the question, there is one key UID which uniquely identifys a JSON record. The issue with my data is that whatever writes to the JSON files seems to write multiple times occasionally. In the json file before I do the map, there are about 30 keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the distinct call in dask.bag is fairly naive.  It gets the unique elements of every partition, and then merges those together into a single partition and gets the distinct elements of those.  It is only reasonable to use if you expect the result to fit in memory.